# Update object instead of inserting with Doctrine using assignIdentifier()

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine

I'm pretty new to Doctrine, but as I understand it, the `assignIdentifier()` method is supposed to tell Doctrine to update the relevant row into the database instead of inserting a new one.

I have an object that I'm building through a workflow, so the identifier has an `id` of `null` until I call `$object->save();` which inserts it, and this does work.

If however I call `$object->assignIdentifier($newobj->id);` and then `$object->save();` it does nothing - it does not insert a new row and does not update the old one.

If a certain condition is true, I want to pull a different record out of the DB and update that row instead of inserting the new one.

Am I understanding something wrong here?

Some code to illustrate:

```
if($this->object->payments > 0) {           
    $older_payment = Doctrine_Query::create()
       ->from('OldPaid p')
       ->where('p.dealid = ?', $this->object->transid)
       ->fetchOne()
    ;

    $this->object->assignIdentifier($older_payment->id);
}

$this->object->save();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, if you retrieve a record, you can update it with the `save()` method. Doctrine recognizes this (since the PK doesn't change) and updates the record.

From the [docs](http://www.doctrine-project.org/documentation/manual/1_1/e+n/component-overview:record:updating-records):

> Updating objects is very easy, you
>   just call the Doctrine_Record::save() 
>   method

Another way can be [`replace()`](http://www.doctrine-project.org/documentation/manual/1_2/zh/component-overview:record:replacing-records), but I usually use just `save()` and does either the saving or the updating if the record already exists.

As far as I can read from the description of `assignIdentifier()` never used it myself) it will only work with retrieving an object by its ID, so updating something with this method will not work.

Answer (score 2):

Like i got to know, save() will not update an existing record with autoincrement on ID.
I have the same problem using doctrine 1.2.

an idea i have use this one, the only workaroung i found:

```
$query = Doctrine_Query::create()->update('OldPaid');
$query->set($yourFieldname, '?', $yourValue);
$query->addwhere('p.dealid = ?', $this->object->transid);
$query->execute();
```

Thiw will function when a record is in the DN with the primaryKey dealid = $this->object->transid.

greeting m